# How to stop v-click-outside from triggering on internal v-select components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've been trying to make a card component that closes if you click anywhere on the outside. But the issue is that v-click-outside gets triggered when I click on an item in the v-select dropdown menu inside of that card. How do I prevent child components from triggering v-click-outside?

```
<v-card v-click-outside="handleClickOutside">
   <v-select
     :items="items"
     v-model="currentItem"
   ></v-select>
</v-card>
```

Comment: Try `v-click-outside.self=`  It may or may not work depending on the directive implementation

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to `v-click-outside` [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-click-outside/#argument), it accepts "A callback or options object.". Object looks like this:

```js
{
  handler: (e: Event) => void,
  closeConditional ? : (e: Event) => boolean,
  include ? : () => HTMLElement[]
}
```

For `handler` pass your function and for `include` you have to specify HTML element [(example)](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/click-outside/#include). To prevent trigger `v-click-outside` when you are using `v-select` you need to include `.v-select-list`.

In your case the solution will look like this:

```html
<v-card v-click-outside="{
    handler: handleClickOutside,
    include: includeFunction
}">
...

<script>
  ...
  methods: {
    includeFunction(){
        //visible elements
        const tempArray = [document.querySelector('.included')]
         
          if (document.querySelector('.v-select-list')) {
            //push the element to array when it is visible
            arr.push(document.querySelector('.v-select-list'))
            
          }
          return tempArray
    }
    ...
  }
</script>
```